# Are "$S$-monoids" known to be good for anything?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, monoid

I came up with the following...

> **...Definition.**
>
> Let $(S,\wedge,1_S)$ denote a fixed but arbitrary monoid.
>
> (In the examples I have in mind, $S$ is always commutative and idempotent. But the definition makes sense irrespective.)
>
> Then by an "$S$-monoid," let us mean a monoid $(M,\circ,1_M)$ together with:
>
> - a homomorphism $S \rightarrow M,$ denoted $s \mapsto \overline{s}$
> - an action $M \times S \rightarrow S,$ denoted $m,s \mapsto m \star s,$ satisfying the identities $$m \star (s \wedge s') = (m\star s) \wedge (m\star s') \;\;\mbox{ and }\;\; m\star 1_S = 1_S$$
>
> satisfying a "deformed" (and weakened) version of commutativity:
>
> $$m \circ \overline{s} = \overline{m \star s} \circ m$$

**Main Example.** Let $(C,\wedge,1_C)$ denote a commutative monoid. Write $\mathrm{Idem}(C)$ for the subset of idempotent elements of $C$. Then $\mathrm{Idem}(C)$ is itself a monoid (and necessarily commutative and idempotent; not that it matters here.)

I claim $\mathrm{End}(C)$ can be viewed as an $\mathrm{Idem}(C)$-monoid as follows:

Given $s \in \mathrm{Idem}(C)$, we define $\overline{s} : C \rightarrow C$ by left multiplication:

$$\overline{s}(c) = s \wedge c$$

Given $m \in \mathrm{End}(C)$ and $s \in \mathrm{Idem}(C)$, we define $m \star s$ by evaluation:

$$m\star s = m(s)$$

(This works because endomorphisms preserve the property of being idempotent, so $m(s)$ is always idempotent, given that $s$ is.)

The verification of deformed commutativity is straightforward. Consider $m \in \mathrm{End}(C)$, $s \in \mathrm{Idem}(C)$ and $c \in C$. Then:  $$(m \circ \overline{s})(c) = m(\overline{s}(c)) = m(s \wedge c) = m(s) \wedge m(c)$$

$$= (m \star s) \wedge m(c) = \overline{m \star s}(m(c)) = (\overline{m \star s} \circ m)(c)$$

We conclude that $$m \circ \overline{s} = \overline{m \star s} \circ m,$$ as required.

> **Question.** Are $S$-monoids known to be good for anything? If so, what are they called in the literature, and where can I learn more about them?

Comment: I don't know if an $S-$monoid is *mathematically* usefull, but I know about a mathematician that works in NOKIA precisely in this things. How is she working there? I don't know. I'll try to contact her for a usefull answer.

Comment: @sinbadh, that would be lovely!

Comment: Hm, what a strange choice to call the set which is acting by the set it is acting upon. It clashes with established terminology like this: $X$ is a $G$-set if it has some action $G\times  X\to X$. A more likely name would be something like "$S$ is an (adjective) $M$-monoid." But anyhow, may I ask how you came upon the construction? Just through the context of the 'main example'?

Comment: @rschwieb, regarding terminology, that's a good point. Yes, I came up with it through the 'main example'. Essentially, I started off with the idea that if $t,s \in C$ are idempotent, then $\overline{s} : C \rightarrow C$ is an idempotent endomorphism, and $\overline{s} \circ \overline{t} = \overline{t} \circ \overline{s}.$ We can ask: is $\overline{s}$ always central in $\mathrm{End}(C)$? Its not, but since you can prove an identity that tells you exactly how to "commute" $\overline{s}$ across $m,$ hence I decided to try thinking of $\mathrm{End}(C)$ as a monoid with further structure.

Comment: This produced the question, which is implicitly: is this further structure known to be good for anything? I should add that at the back of my mind, the "internalization problem" lingers: I want to know about the possibility of adjoining elements to $C$ to obtain something bigger, call it $C'$, such that the idempotent endomorphisms of $C$ that are central in $\mathrm{End}(C)$ are all represented somehow as elements of $C'$.